# Designing boost converter for a supercapacitor source and LED load

Tags: led, power-electronics, energy, discharge, supercapacitor

I have a 2.7 V 100 F supercap, that would equal 364.50 J of energy based on E = 1/2CV^2. If my load is a series of 4 LEDs with a stack forward voltage of 12 V and forward current of 3 A that would equate to a power of 36 W based on P = VI. We know that P = E/t. Hence maximum time that the Load will be on with steady power is ~2-5 s, I'll be strobing the LEDs at 10 Hz and 30% duty cycle, so might be able to get a bit more time. Well that's the theoretical capacity.

A few more calculations for a more realistic look at this, considering how the voltages and current changes with discharge, lead to:

[image]

What I'm struggling to understand is in designing a boost circuit for this. I've looked at commercial and booster ICs to no avail. Some issues, the booster ICs that go down to 0.7 V input only have a max output of 5 V. While booster circuits with a higher voltage cap have like a 3.7 V min input. Since we aren't working with a battery but a supercap with much greater power output. I have no idea how to approach this design because the voltage is dropping by self discharge and the current consequently increases.

**NOTE**: Only reason I'm looking at such a low energy solution is the fact that I'm looking to power the load for hardly 1.5-5 s. Potentially expanding to larger power loads for a similar run time such as 18 A and 12 V with a slightly larger capacitance of course.

Comment: You *might* be able to use one of the 5 V max output parts with a flyback transformer in order to get a higher voltage out.  The devil is in the details.

Comment: It's all about power tho, something with 5V max output and 3A isn't going to translate to 12V and 3A. How is current from a supercap even determined, we're using time to discharge as a parameter in calculation right?

Comment: @JohnD It's all quite confusing, since it's unlike a battery which supplies current based on the load. Theoretically output current at 2.7V with an ESR of 0.011mOhm should be 245A yet peak switching current is 71A. How to convert 2.7V and 71A and consequently higher currents as the voltage drops into a low powered 36W load - is there some direction u can give to approach design?

Comment: Yes, of course, the power is definitely the issue, there *probably* isn't a suitable part but I haven't done a survey of all available parts.   36 W at 1 V is 36 A, so operating down to very low Vin isn't going to give you much extra time anyway.

Comment: If you put a constant power load (like a boost converter providing a steady 36 W) then the discharge is calculated as in the explanation here: https://licn.typepad.com/my_weblog/2011/03/capacitor-voltage-decay-at-constant-power-john-dunn-consultant-ambertec-pe-pc.html

Comment: The cap at low voltage stores too low energy to bother since energy decreases with voltage square (E=0.5CUU).

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I understand the energy considerations, only reason i'm looking at this design is that anywhere between 2-5s of run time is acceptable

Comment: @JohnD that is an informative link. for 100F cap, the discharge time for a 36W load is 7seconds assuming  starting voltage is 2.5V and finished voltage (when discharge is stopped) is 1V. How do I figure out what the stop or minimum voltage of the super cap should be. Is that based on understanding the current characteristic? Main question is at 1V does the capacitor have enough energy for any boost to supply the required power to the load. And how one should go about determining such a thing

Comment: Sorry that was a dumb question, that's by calculating the energy. But then that would mean at even 0.1V the capacitor should theoretically have the power to supply 36W to the load for 0.013 seconds. So, ig minimum voltage ain't a concern then, is that deduction accurate @JohnD

Comment: Well, at 0.1 V the current would be more than 360 A, so if your cap and boost converter were ideal, yes.  Otherwise the ESR and max discharge of your cap, and the max input current capability of your boost (inductor rating etc.) as well as the minimum input voltage of the boost will limit what you can do to a much higher voltage.

Comment: If you can’t find a regulator, how about a controller+external transistor? Perhaps even a boost converter just to be able to use standard controllers and not exotic extra low voltage ones.

Comment: Have you checked the current capability of the super cap - even at max voltage you’re looking at over 13A.  If the cap is indeed good for current in the 10s of amps then what you want to do is technically possible but as others have stated there’s little point in trying to discharge all the way to zero.  It’s unlikely you’ll find an off the shelf solution but you may have some success with a boost chip and some discrete components.  I’d suggest flyback mode since this topology allows a wide range of input:output voltage ratios.

Comment: @winny can you expand on a "controller + external transistor" design please.

Comment: @Frog https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/87/eaton_tv_supercapacitors_cylindrical_cells_data_sh-1608777.pdf look at the 100F capacitor in the datasheet. Current capability is well over 13As. I now understand how pointless it is discharging to 0V. How'd you arrive at 13A's tho for maximum voltage shouldn't it be 2.7/0.011 =~245As. That's one place i'm confused about - calculation is way over the datasheet peek current. Usage of a flyback mode is a good tip, thanks. What's the best way to determine if the current is good for over a set time?

Comment: @Frog i understood how you got 13As, not exactly sure now cuz datasheet shows peak switching current and max continuous current which is 11.3As hence less that 13.5As.

Comment: 18650 INR battery is about the same size as the cap, cheaper, and will deliver 36W without trouble. Instead of 4 LEDs in series, consider 2x2 LEDs in series or other arrangement to make DC-DC design simpler.

Comment: @bobflux I've actually completed a working design with a 70C lipo battery for a 54W led strip (27v 2A) using a constant current boost driver and it works fine. I'm curious in designing one with supercaps - hence my question.

Comment: Why not design for, say, 4 25 F capacitors?

Comment: @Roshan 13A is based on 36W/2.7V, which gives the initial mean input current, that will go up as the input voltage drops, and of course any switcher’s peak current will be higher than the mean, although that can be mitigated with additional input caps.

Comment: @Frog Wait I thought output current from a supercap was independent of the load, but if what you say is true that does indeed make sense. Can you please elucidate how additional input caps would mitigate the situation?

Comment: @greybeard space constraints for the design. I'm essentially redesigning what what worked when using a high c rating battery with a single or at max two capacitors, no space available past that.

Comment: @Roshan I’m thinking about what’s required by the load rather than what’s available from the source; 36W calls for 13A at 2.6V, 36A at 1V.  That’s assuming 100% efficiency, you can expect 80% and maybe achieve 90% or so.

Comment: In a mid-range case where you’d need to draw let’s say 25A, you might see a peak current of 40A.  If the super cap can’t provide that directly then you could add some electrolytic or ceramic caps that have a higher ripple capacity; they could provide more instantaneous current than the supercap and recharge while the switcher isn’t drawing current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, using a very low voltage boost regulator to pump up a 5 V rail to allow a bog-standard boost *controller* and external MOSFET to do the heavy lifting. For generating 5 V, MAX17220 will operate down to 0.4 V and will boost to 5 V. At 5 V, you have tens if not hundreds of boost controllers to choose from. I picked MCP1632 at random which was in stock but does not feature synchronous rectification.

This is just a simplification to push you in the right direction. You need to calculate all values. Not all pins are drawn and several things are omitted. Choose a MOSFET and Schottky which can handle your full peak current and with low enough Vgsth to operate on 5 V.

Ideally, choose a synchronous rectifier boost for your main power stage which can do the current limiting for your LEDs directly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO4eBW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I just realized the MCP1632 is a better choice for LED drive than I first thought as it have a current source and allow you to program the Vref. This allows you to set it to a very low value with R_r and set your current sense resistor R4 to a low value to not burn excessive power at 3 A. Set it with 3*R4=50µ*R_r. Here is how it would look with direct LED drive:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKmDPv.png)</sup>

Ignoring all DC-DC converter losses, this is the minimum current you are looking at for a 12 V 3 A load. It would take ever increasing inductor saturation current and low Rdson on your MOSFET to extract more energy from your supercap. If you want to play around with it yourself, you can create a constant power load with a resistor fed by a rail named Vcap and set the resistor value to R=limit(1m,V(Vcap)**2/36,1000) in LTspice, should be very similar in other SPICE flavors (get it?). 36 is your load in W here. 1m and 1000 are your lower and upper bound for how far it will go. I would say it looks uneconomical at 0.8 V to go any further at that high power level. At 40 A, you are probably better off with interleaving several boost converters, if not for MOSFET losses, than for inductor size.

[image]

Comment: very informative answer, I understand things aren't quite accurate. What would be the best way to determine the voltage drop of the supercapacitor as a function of time with two dc-dc controllers here?

Comment: @Roshan You are most welcome! You can ignore the 5 V pump, it will consume tens of mW. The 12 V boost one will however do its damndest to keep the output current 3 A to your LEDs until it either hits it max duty cycle limit or peak current limit set by CS. You can model it as a constant power load of you want to simulate it.

Comment: I've gone through the datasheet and am still un clear with how the CS pin is used to set the peak current value, I know this is leaning away from the main question. If possible some insight on this, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you also mind clarifying what the input current from the supercap to the boost will look like, I still keep going back to thinking 2.7V, 100F so, it'll start at >13A current and keep on increasing. Only reason i'm concerned about that is the input current capabilities of boost controllers. I think it's the intermediary boost that's just messing up with this fundamental understanding between source and load.

Comment: @Roshan See my update.